# Javascript submit function not working.

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<html><head>
<script>
function submit() {
   document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>
</head>
        <body>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <h1> AWB_NO</h1>
    <input type=text name="excel" onchange="submit()" >
    </br>
    </form>
        <?php
session_start();
$vars = $_COOKIE['var1'];
//$vars=$_GET['doc'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
    $_SESSION['items'] = array();
}

$var='';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $db="greenmobiles";
    $table="manifest";
    $var=$_POST['excel'];
    //$vars=$_POST['doc'];    
    mysql_connect("$host","$user","$password") or die("Cannot Connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db") or die("Cannot select DB!");    
    /*$sqlcommand="SELECT document_no FROM manifest WHERE (document_no = '$vars')";
    $doc_res = mysql_query($sqlcommand);
   while($col = mysql_fetch_array($doc_res)){
   if($col['document_no']==$vars)
    {
        echo "Document number is correct</br>";
        break;
    }}
    if($col['document_no']!==$vars)
    {
        echo "Please check the document no entered";
        exit(0);

    }*/
      if (in_array($var,$_SESSION['items']))
    {
        echo "<script>alert('oops! This item has already been scanned!')</script>";
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE (awb_no = '$var')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "tracking id present in the manifest</br>";
} 
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Tracking id is not present in the manifest!')</script>";

}
 $sqli = "SELECT * FROM manifest WHERE (awb_no = '$var') AND (document_no='$vars')";
$result1 = mysql_query($sqli);  
if (mysql_num_rows($result1)) 
{
   echo "The tracking id matches with the document no.";
    # code...
}
else
{
echo "<script>alert('Tracking id does not belong to the document number entered.')</script>";
exit(0);
} 

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $_SESSION['data'][] = $row['awb_no'];
        $_SESSION['items'] = $_SESSION['data'];
   }
     echo"The new value has been scanned!</br>";
  echo "<hr>";
  echo "The tracking id's of the currently scanned items are given below<br><hr>";
  foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $x => $value)
   {
    echo "$value";
    echo "<br>";
        # code...
   }

  }
}
else
{
    session_destroy();
}
?>
</body>
    </html>
```

Hey! I am new to javascript,php and html. Here when i am trying to use the javascript submit instead of the submit button,my php script does not seem to execute.How to go about this problem?Please do help! P.S I do not want to use the submit button.

Comment: Please read stackoverflow basic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Saty please take a look at [OnChange event in Input text](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange2). **Pramod S**, you should wait for your input to be loaded before binding it to an event. Take a look at EventListener [DOM Content Loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Comment: @Zeratops thanks for updating me for providing important information!!!

Comment: @Zeratops how would i apply that here? A small example pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors on your script.
Active your php errors displays :

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

First, the session must be started BEFORE to send headers.
So begin the file with :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
...
```

Second, the global $_POST contains an array with 'name' attributes

```
<input type=text name="excel" onchange="submit()" >
<?php
if(isset($_POST['excel'])) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank u for the tip! Now the php script is executing,but not properly as it is always executing the if clause where "oops the item is already scanned", even though $var is not in the $_SESSIONS array

Comment: Yup, I got it. Thank  so much. Ignore the previous comment

Comment: I don't know, you must display variables for debug : var_dump($_SESSION['items']); var_dump($var);

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) is wrong type `if(isset($_POST['name']))`
```